# run arbitrary code according to video timing in videojs

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, video.js, popcornjs

Is it possible for [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) to run arbitrary code ( JavaScript functions ) according to video timing?

Till now we were using Popcorn.js with its [Code](http://popcornjs.org/popcorn-docs/plugins/#Code) plugin, but we need to migrate to another library.

Answer (score 0):

You can, using this [cuepoints plugin](https://github.com/cladera/videojs-cuepoints). The syntax is similar:

```
videojs("myVideo").ready(function(){
  this.cuepoints();
  this.addCuepoint({
    start: 2,
    end: 5,
    onStart: function(params){
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="Hello";
    },
    onEnd: function(params){
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML="Bye";
    }, 
    params: {error: false}
  });
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGgwE